# VB.NET: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, format, iif

With the following snippet

```
Foo = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFoo.Text), 0, Integer.Parse(txtFoo.Text.Trim))
```

I get the error when I submit the field without a value: "Input string was not in a correct format."
I don't have any space or something else and String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFoo.Text) returns true. What is wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**IIF** will evaluate:

```
Integer.Parse(txtFoo.Text.Trim)
```

irrespective of whether:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFoo.Text)
```

is true or not (as it is just a function with three arguments passed to it, so all arguments must be valid). So even if `txtFoo.text is empty`, it's still trying to Parse it to an Integer in this case.

If you're using VS2008, you can use the IF operator instead which will short-circuit as you're expecting IIF to do.

Comment: `IIf` actually *is* a function, it doesn’t just behave like one.

Comment: ... and `If` is an *operator*, so it isn't a function, and it doesn't behave like one either +1 though

Answer (score 1):

IIf is a function call rather than a true conditional operator, and that means both arguments have to be evaluated.  Thus, it just attempts to call Integer.Parse() if your string is Null/Nothing.

If you're using Visual Studio 2008 or later, it's only a one character difference to fix your  problem:

```
Foo = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFoo.Text), 0, Integer.Parse(txtFoo.Text.Trim())
```

This version of the `If` keyword is actually a true conditional operator that will do the short-circuit evaluation of arguments as expected.

If you're using Visual Studio 2005 or earlier, you fix it like this:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFoo.Text) Then Foo = 0 Else Foo = Integer.Parse(txtFoo.Text.Trim())
```

Answer (score 1):

IIf is not a true ternary operator, it actually evaluates *both* parameter expressions. You probably want to use the If operator instead (VS 2008+).

You'd simply say

```
If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFoo.Text), 0, Integer.Parse(txtFoo.Text.Trim()))
```

Answer (score 0):

One difference between the conditional and the "else" portion is the trimming of the string. You could try trimming the string before calling `IsNullOrEmpty`.

```
Foo = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFoo.Text.Trim), 0, Integer.Parse(txtFoo.Text.Trim))
```